# Will disabling the device UDID in developer account disable my ipad to continue run the app?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I added an iPad on developer account under devices and then installed an ipa for an application on that iPad for testing. My question is that if I disable the UDID of that iPad in developer account, will the ipa of that app stop running on that iPad too?

Comment: No, not unless you remove the profile from the iPad itself

Comment: It won't be a problem until you create a new provisioning profile and build the app with the new profile. The existing app will run until the previous provisioning profile on the device expires.

Comment: @rmaddy, so If I delete the old provisioning profile (used in the ipa now running on the test iPad) from my account, will it disable the app on the test iPad ?

Comment: Not at all. Only if you delete it from the device.

Comment: @rmmaddy. So there is no way of wiping/disabling the beta app given to testers for testing on their iPads through my developer account ? Sorry if this is a naive question but I cannot find much information about this on internet.

Comment: If that is your question then post that as your question. But no, there is no way to make a beta app stop working unless you've written in code that makes it stop somehow. It will function until the provisioning profile used to install the app expires which could be up to 1 year from installation.